# I/m getting error msg: Variable does not exists: spt in line no 25

Tags: apex, rollback, savepoint

```java
account acc = [select id, name from account limit 1];
Opportunity Opp = new opportunity();
list<opportunity> Listopp = new list <opportunity> ();
if (acc!=null)
{
    for (integer i=0;i<=160;i++)
    {
        opp.name = 'New name'+i;
        opp.type= 'new customer';
        opp.amount=20000;
        opp.stagename='Qualification';
        opp.closedate=system.today(); 
        opp.accountid=acc.id;
        Listopp.add(opp);   //for each loop
    }

    try{
        savepoint spt = database.setSavepoint();
        insert listopp;
    }
    catch (exception e)
    {
        system.debug(e);
        database.rollback(spt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: There are issues with this code beyond the syntax error you're getting. `acc` will never be null (you'd get an exception if there were 0 accounts), and declaring `opp` outside of the loop means you'll end up re-using the same opp over and over (leading to a "duplicate item in list" exception when you try to insert the list.

Answer (score 5):

Variables have local scope: they only live inside the block of code they're declared within.
You declared `savepoint spt` inside the `try`, that's why it doesn't exist in the `catch` block.
Move the declaration outside the `try` block and it will be visible in the `catch`:

```
Savepoint spt = Database.setSavepoint();
try {
    insert listopp;
} catch (exception e) {
    System.debug(e);
    database.rollback(spt);
}
```

Anyway you don't need a savepoint there: using `insert aList` is the same of [`Database.insert(aList, true)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_insert_2), so even if only a single record of the list cannot be inserted, the whole insert is reverted.

Comment: Note for others: You only need to declare the variable outside of the "try" block to be able to set it in the "try" block and use it in the "catch" block. Beyond that though, I'd say that the try/catch here is bad and should likely be completely removed ("pokemon" catch, not doing anything of value in the catch, rollback is automatic if the exception isn't caught).